# How to add a new block in Editor.js

Tags: javascript, editor, editorjs

i am using [Editor.js](https://editorjs.io/) and i do not know how to add a new block in the editor via javascript, e.g.

I've created the editor by docs:

```
const editor = new EditorJS({
      holderId: 'codex-editor',
      autofocus: true,
      data: {
        "time": 1550476186479,
        "blocks": [
           {
            type: 'paragraph', 
            data: {
             text: 'Hello world'
            }
           }
        ]
      },
      onReady: () => {
        console.log('Editor.js is ready to work!');
      }
    })
```

But i cannot add any new text, i've tried the method:

```
const newBlock = {
      type: 'paragraph', 
      data: {
          text: 'Hello world'
      }
    };
editor.configuration.data.blocks.push(newBlock);
```

It does not help, `editor.configuration.data.blocks` updates himself values but added values does not display in Editor.js view.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `blocks.insert()` API method. This feature is available since 2.15 version

https://editorjs.io/blocks#insert

Comment: Hi, if I want to create a new block that inserts other blocks, how could I do this? Ie. a tools named "section" that inserts a "header" and "paragraph"? I've looked at the documentation but they all seem for completely custom blocks, what I would like is to insert multiple blocks when a single button (custom tool - "section") is clicked in the add block menu "+"? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

hopefully this example of mine will help you. I was doing a photo saving using Firebase. After saving it, I want to insert the image inside editorjs. Here's the code of how I do it.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    task.snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        finalize( () => {
          ref.getDownloadURL()
            .subscribe(url => {
              console.log(url);
              this.editor.blocks.insert(
                "image",
                {
                  file: {
                    url : "https://www.tesla.com/tesla_theme/assets/img/_vehicle_redesign/roadster_and_semi/roadster/hero.jpg"
                  },
                  caption : "Roadster // tesla.com",
                  withBorder : false,
                  withBackground : false,
                  stretched : true
                })
            },error => {
              console.log(error)
            })
        }))
      .subscribe( url => {
        if(url){ console.log(url); }
      })
```